# Term for percent, percentage, fraction, scale factor?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

I have functions that *conceptually* all return the same thing, but the result can take different forms:

```
function GetThingy()
```

There are four different functions, each can return different things:

- `0.071` (a `float` value representing an increase of 7.1%)
- `7.1` (a `float` value representing an increase of 7.1%)
- `1.071` (a `float` value representing an increase of 7.1%)
- `"7.1%"` (a `string` value representing a percentage of 7.1%)

What *terms* can I use to help document these functions return values?

I've come up with my own terminology:

- **fraction**: A *fraction* of one; where the value is understood to be between 0..1 (e.g. `0.07` represents 7%)
- **percent**: A *per-one-hundred* value; where the value is understood to be between 0..100 (e.g. `7` represents 7%) **Note**: This contrasts with a *fraction*, with is per-one, rather than per-hundred
- **factor**: [A *scale factor*, that can be used to directly multiply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.scalecontrol.aspx); understood to be equivalent to **1+fraction** (e.g. `1.07` implies an increase of 7%)
- **percentage**: A *string* that contains the actual **percent character** (i.e. **%**), suitable for display to the user, or cases that prefer the localized text (e.g. `"7%"` implies 7%)

So applying my own naming scheme to the functions:

- `GetThingyFraction()` = 0.071
- `GetThingyPercent()` = 7.1
- `GetThingyFactor()` = 1.071
- `GetThingyPercentage()`= "7.1%"

What say you?

Comment: Hmm, this *should* have been a good question for English.SE. Not sure what's wrong with those people. It's quite irrelevant to the question that you're writing a program or naming a function.

Comment: Whatever - use the convention that works for you and your team, document it, and be consistent.  I don't believe you should expect validation and adoption from this site.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not having four functions that essentially all do the same thing.  Instead, have one getter (that always returns a "fraction"), and then helper functions which can convert from one format to another.

Comment: @duffymo i seek neither validation, nor require adoption. i am asking for the correct terms. If i talk about using SHA1 to "*encrypt*" my passwords, i am sure i would hear about the correct terminology.

Comment: I would not call help naming a method a programming question.  Use inline documentation to describe the functions.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The functions, and their return values, are set in legacy code. i am certainly not going to rework all the logic surrounding them. But i can try to clarify the language to make it easier to follow. Either way, my *reasons* are unimportant.

Comment: That's why this was a comment, not an answer...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth But there are not four functions that do the same thing.  There are 4 different unique outputs.

Comment: Maybe the people at English.S.E. were incensed at your failure to capitalize "I".

Comment: @BalamBalam: They all return the same concept, just with different formatting.

Comment: @Beta That's a very personal, very *intentional* choice. You'll see it in all my questions; unless someone has gone back and "fixed" (i.e. broke) my usage.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Excellent, Charlie, they all return different outputs. What are the four different outputs? Name them for me please.

Comment: @Ian: I could only give you my opinion, which is why this question is off-topic for SO...  (I don't know much about the English SE, but it sounds like this would have been on-topic there.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Maybe I am missing something but 0.071, 7.1, and 1.071 are different numbers.   How do you format 7.1 to 1.071?

Comment: @BalamBalam: By writing a helper function to perform the conversion for you.  This leads to less code duplication, a less-cluttered interface, and code that is easier to maintain (in general: I'm assuming that the OP has more than one `thingy` in his interface).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I hear you but for a single conversion it is not less code.  I agree it is messed up.  To encourage this design pattern with general conversion is not taking the code forward.

Comment: @BalamBalam. Think of a sales tax rate of 7%: `7`, `0.07`, `1.07`. They are all representations of the same concept. You do have to **use** them differently (`total = subTotal*(1+taxRate/100)`, `total = subTotal*(1+taxRate)`, `total = subTotal*taxRate`). But they're the same thing nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure there is an "answer" to this, but naming the functions as you have demonstrated makes it very easy for the consumer to understand what they are getting back.  I like the terms you have chosen as well.

Are you planning on implementing all four (or n) flavors of each function, or is this strictly a naming question for when different operations process the result differently?

I am not so sure about the utility of the "percentage" version.  Typically making strings for UI of messages should be handled in the presentation, not in the computation.  The presentation would determine how many decimal places, "%" vs. "pct" vs "percent", etc.

Comment: I also think the names are fine, but I'd use the term `FormatThingy` instead of `GetThingy`, and create one function with a parameter defining what kind of format to return. The value is always the same, it's simply the formatting that's different.

Comment: Unless the function is actually computing... so it could be GetDiscountPercent() or GetInterestFactor()

Comment: In my case i am maintaining some legacy code that have functions that return "percents". But different functions return them as different "kinds": `7`, `0.07`, `1.07`. Trying to decipher what each function returns is proving very tedious and difficult (the function names don't give any indication of what they return). And there's no comments indicating what form of "percentage" they return. So it's time to bring order to the chaos.  `7`=*percent*, `.07`=*fraction*, `1.07`=*factor*. And then, when i need to show the values, `7%`=*percentage*. Or not....i dunno.

Comment: Renaming legacy functions to properly identify the return content sounds like an excellent idea, and will make the consuming code more readable as well.

Comment: Examples from code i've adopted: `function getHealingPercentBonus()` returns `1.07`. `function getSpellCrit()` returns `4.3`. `function getHealingFactor()` returns `0.02`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you've just about got it, but I'd add the word "Increase" in some places, and put your examples in the documentation/comments:

GetThingyFractionIncrease() [e.g. 0.071 represents an increase of 7.1%]

GetThingyPercentIncrease() [e.g. 7.1 represents an increase of 7.1%]

GetThingyFactor() [e.g. 1.071 represents an increase of 7.1%]

GetThingyPercentageString() [e.g. "7.1%" represents an increase of 7.1%]

Answer (score 0):

Even though your tag is language-agnostic, I'm assuming that you are writing in a modern Object-Oriented Programming language.

If you had a `Thingy` class with a `thingy` object that had a private fraction, then you could allow public access through methods like these:

- double thingy.asFractionIncrease
- double thingy.asPercentIncrease
- double thingy.asFactor
- String thingy.asPercentIncreaseString

P.S. I'm going to upvote your EL&U posting. As of this moment, this will get you back to 0 and you'll be net positive on the reputation